# setBackground for the QTableWidgetItem doesnt work

Tags: python, pyqt5

```py
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore

class Test(QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("$",self.background()) # note
        try_1 = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor("orange"))
        print(try_1)
        self.setBackground(try_1)
        print("$",self.background()) # remains same
        try_2 = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor("orange"))
        print(try_2)
        self.setData(QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole, try_2)
        print("$",self.background()) # same

Test()
```

**setData() and self.setBackground() doesn't change the QBrush object** of `QTableWidgetItem`.
**we can see that self. background() returns the same object**

setForeground and setFont works, but it doesn't work for the Background is there another way to set background for the QTableWidgetItem so that **i can use it in QHeaderView**?

I have visited lots of similar posts but they didn't have any solutions.

Comment: Have you tried using the custom item in a table widget?

Comment: yes, but i need this in case for the HeaderView

Comment: Header views don't use all the data roles of their items. Whether or not `Qt.BackgroundRole` is used depends on the current style. For example for "Fusion" and "Windows" styles the background role of items is used in the header view but not for the "windowsvista" style.

Comment: when I checked the source code 147th line of [This](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qtablewidget.h.html#_ZN16QTableWidgetItem13setBackgroundERK6QBrush), they used setData with background role

Comment: @Heike i guess that's the reason why setData method doesn't work, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to using the following code:

```
self.table.horizontalHeaderItem(col).setBackground(QtGui.QColor("green"))
```

"col" refers to the column of your table.
Note: set 'Fusion' style in your app.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
  app.setStyle(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.create('Fusion')) # won't work on windows style.
```